# Enable breadcrumb on mobile

Tags: breadcrumbs

Is there a way to enable breadcrumb on mobile view for Magento 2? I've looked through the Magento docs but there doesn't seem to be any mention of mobile view anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly put this code in the CSS file

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
.breadcrumbs {
    display: block;
}
```